# SwiftUI picker save return object

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-picker

I have a background in .NET backend and I have decided to learn swift.
It is going very well, but I have a few issues in SwiftUI.
My problem right now is with the picker.

My goal is to pick an item from the picker, return the object and save the object in a variable, so I can post it to api.

The picker is a list of recipes from API, with: name and ID.

I can populate the picker just fine and get the object back, but I can’t save it.

I got the picker and with the selection I can easy get the name.
But how do I save the full object?

```
Picker("Pick a recipe", selection: $selectedItem) {
        ForEach(recipes, id: \.self) { recipe in 
            Text(recipe.name) 
// var res = recipe - I can’t do that, what do I do then?
        }
    }
```

Comment: The selection Item should have the whole object, if it doesn’t you can specify by adding the tag but it should be there just tie that variable to your object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The whole object is there but I can’t save it in a variable..

Comment: The `selectedItem` **is** the variable that the selection is saved into. Use it in your code elsewhere as required.

Comment: The selection is the variable, you can use onChange to see when the selection changed and do something there. The body by itself isn’t for assignments, it is just for displaying you need an action block.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) you are looking at SwiftUI the wrong way there are big differences with other languages.

Comment: just use .onChange(of: selectedItem, perform : { 
// do anything here you want with the actual selected item
})